# Payflow - Error code 52 Insufficient permissions to perform transaction

Tags: payflowlink

I had created a payflow test account and used php SDK library for working on it. For a sale transaction, it gives a response that 'Insufficient permissions to perform transaction'. Am newbie to the payflow integration. The error code it retrives is 52 which doesnot exist in their doc.
The response was

```
[RESULT] => 52
[PNREF] => V10A4F5B2C41
[RESPMSG] => Insufficient permissions to perform transaction
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the API user that you are using has the correct permissions if you have more than one set up on your account.  Also if you have more than one user on your account, try testing with a different one.

Comment: How can I find out whether I have a Payflow Link account or Payflow Pro?